# Variable used in function name

Tags: jquery

I'm making a helper function that, amongst other things adds or removes a class. The function needs to be able to do either as there doesn't seem any point in making two functions with the only difference being one adds a class the other removes it. So:

```
function kalf_addRow( type, action ) {
    found = $("."+type).not(".row-vis").first();
    found.slideDown();
    $(found).[INSERT 'action' IN HERE]Class("row-vis");     
}
```

I would pass it either "add" or "remove" as the "action" parameter and then need it inserted where shown. I would need to do similar for the slideDown too but it's basically the same problem.

Comment: jQuery has a `toggleClass` function: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As asawyer said, you could use `toggleClass`.

```
$(found).toggleClass("row-vis", action == 'add');
```

Or another way would be to use an `if`.  Or you could do this

```
$(found)[action + 'Class']("row-vis");
```

Comment: because I don't think very clearly! Fair answer, would solve both issues. Thanks for the actual answer too, worth knowing for the future.